# how do i convert HTML string to JSON with PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, string

Is there a way to convert HTML string to JSON with PHP exactly like what toolslick.com html2json converter is doing.

This is an example of the html string

```
<html>
<body>
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm expecting a json like:

```
{
  "html": {
    "body": {
      "table": {
        "@style": "width: 100%",
        "tr": [
          {
            "th": [
              "Firstname",
              "Lastname",
              "Age"
            ]
          },
          {
            "td": [
              "Jill",
              "Smith",
              "50"
            ]
          },
          {
            "td": [
              "Eve",
              "Jackson",
              "94"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestion would be helpful thanks

Comment: You can use `DOMDocument` to parse it. Then write a recursive function that converts the document structure to JSON.

Comment: @Barmar I'm receiving the HTML as text on the backend

Comment: Right. The `loadHTML()` method will parse it

Comment: @Barmar Please any idea on the recursive function

Answer (score 2):

If the HTML is valid you could try using SimpleXML and `json_encode` to parse it into JSON:

```
$xml = '<html>
<body>
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>';

$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xml);

echo json_encode($xmlObj);
```

https://3v4l.org/TZ4BP

Comment: Thank you much. It seems to be working on small snippet of HTML, however when a full html page is sent i get this error  *simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 50: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch:*

Comment: If you're getting that error, it must be invalid HTML. And no solution will work.